# Error: Metadata version mismatch for module .../ngx-masonry/ngx-masonry.d.ts, found version 4, expected 3

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, npm, node-modules

ngx-masonry gives the following error- ERROR in Error: Metadata version mismatch for module .../ngx-masonry/ngx-masonry.d.ts, found version 4, expected 3

Specification:
Angular 4
ngx-masonry 1.1.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After spending a whole day I resolved this issue.

What I did:
In ngx-masonry.metadata.json file, I updated the version number from '4' into '3'
and saved the changes and run the project without any error.

Comment: Hello, Do you know if I can use the `ngx-masonry` library to create a collage using Angular? I have seen a few demos where a few pictures are placed next to each other. Do you know of an example where I can maybe also click on the pictures or re-arrange them? Thanks